# Out of range errors while with insert statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, json

I'm having an issue regarding every third insert line of the database I'm trying to create.

Some background, I have a huge .JSON file and used software (sqlizer) to turn it into input statements, however I'm having an issue as you can see here:

[image]

Every third statement or so, I run into a range error, that I'm not sure why is happening since I didn't set a range.

Here is a sample from my insert statements:
http://pastebin.com/j7A4ZJV4

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue? Keep in mind I'm very new to MySQL so forgive me if I've done something tremendously dumb.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you're trying to insert are above the max allowed for a [signed `INT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) column in MySQL:

```
3088727691 > 2147483647
```

You can either switch it to an unsigned `INT` to make the max value 4,294,967,295 or a signed `BIGINT` to give you the room to hit up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Was not aware of that limit! I'll change it when I get back and try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are these IP addresses?  Then use `INT UNSIGNED`.  It stays 4 bytes like you have (instead of 8 bytes for `BIGINT`) and is big enough for the old IPv4 ip addresses.